# Where in Codeigniter do I detect if user is on mobile device?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

I have a CI Bonfire installation and I don't know where can I detect if a user is viewing the page on a mobile device or desktop PC? Is this done directly in front controller `application/core/Base_Controller.php` ?

If user is on desktop PC I need to redirect them to specific page inside my installation. And this must be detectable all over my website in all controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Load User agent Lib

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
```

use this function to detect is mobile

```
$mobile=$this->agent->is_mobile();
if($mobile){
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following check in your root file (Beginning).

```
$isMobile = (bool)preg_match('#\b(ip(hone|od|ad)|android|opera m(ob|in)i|windows (phone|ce)|blackberry|tablet'.
                    '|s(ymbian|eries60|amsung)|p(laybook|alm|rofile/midp|laystation portable)|nokia|fennec|htc[\-_]'.
                    '|mobile|up\.browser|[1-4][0-9]{2}x[1-4][0-9]{2})\b#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );

if(isMobile())
    header("Location: http://m.site.com/");
```

Comment: do you mean the `index.php` in my root? Because index there is titled "Welcome to CI-Bonfire" and only reads "Some things have changed since the last version,.." I doubt this is the controller

Comment: Could you please post your current URL that from where you want to redirect?